# Managed Bean for jersey resource classes

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

is there any valid reason, all jersey resource classes are marked with @ManagedBean annotation. Already, the resource classes are marked with @Path and @Produces jaxrs annotations. is it not sufficient for the container to consider it as a jax-rs resource class?

Comment: I also asked myself this question and discovered the provided answer in Jersey documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[javax.annotation.ManagedBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/ManagedBean.html) is not a jax-rs annotation, and because of that, the container shouldn't assume anything about jax-rs when reading that annotation, so, yes, `@Path` and `@Produces` are enough for the container to consider it as a jax-rs resource. You can use @ManagedBean if you want additional services (non-jax-rs related) to be provided to your resources by the container, check the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/ManagedBean.html).

Answer (score 0):

`@ManagedBean` annotation is required if you want to inject your EJBs in JAX-RS resources without using @Local annotations and interfaces on your EJBs.

Compare the following Jersey documentation topics:

1. https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.javaee.managed
2. https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.javaee.ejb

So you may choose what approach fits your needs well: either to use `@Local` interface + `@Stateless` EJB or to inject your `@Stateless` EJBs without `@Local` interface in your `@ManagedBean` annotated resource.

Also take a look at the official example: https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/managed-beans-webapp